# example for a ring with one element as identity element of both operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Im reading a text and at the beginning it assumes that for all the ring the 1 and 0 element the identity elements are different and I couldn't find any except {0} is there any other?

Comment: If $0 = 1$ then for all $x \in R$, $x = 1 \cdot x = 0 \cdot x = 0$.

Comment: thanx Im removing the question sorry @DanielSchepler

Answer (score 0):

There are not.   Proof:  Let 0=1.

Let $x\in R$  Then $x=1\cdot x=0\cdot x=(0+0)\cdot x=0x+0x$
Hence subtracting $0x$ from both sides, you get $0=x$,   thus if $1=0$, everything must equal 0.